# Problem with setting a value in foreign key column

Tags: foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize.js with SQLite-database and faced a question with setting a value for foreign key. I have the following code:

```
const MessageModel = sequelize.define('MessageModel ', {
    uuid: DataTypes.STRING,
    authorId: DataTypes.STRING,
    // ... other props
  }, {});

const TodoModel = sequelize.define('TodoModel', {
    ownerId: DataTypes.STRING,
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: 'pending'
    }
  }, {});

TodoModel.belongsTo(MessageModel , {
    foreignKey: {
        name: 'messageId',
        field: 'messageId',
        allowNull: false
    },
    targetKey: 'uuid'
});

MessageModel.create({
   uuid: 'testUUIDForExample'
   // other props
}).then(message => {

   console.log(`Message's created successful`);

   TodoModel.create({
      ownerId: 'id-string',
      status: 'test-status',
      messageId: 'testUUIDForExample'
   })
})
```

Sequelize creates MessageModel-row in DB, but it falls when it's trying to generate TodoModel with this err:

```
DatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: foreign key mismatch - "TodoModel" referencing "MessageModel "
    at Query.formatError (C:\Users\lrsvo\web-development\projects\platoon-web-electron\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:432:16)
    at Query._handleQueryResponse (C:\Users\lrsvo\web-development\projects\platoon-web-electron\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:77:18)
    at afterExecute (C:\Users\lrsvo\web-development\projects\platoon-web-electron\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:260:31)
    at Statement.errBack (C:\Users\lrsvo\web-development\projects\platoon-web-electron\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:16:21)

Err.original.message: "SQLITE_ERROR: foreign key mismatch - "TodoModel" referencing "MessageModel"
```

Generated SQL:

```
"INSERT INTO `TodoModel` (`id`,`ownerId`,`status`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`messageId`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5);"
```

My TodoModel table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE "TodoModel" (
    "id"            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "ownerId"   VARCHAR(255),
    "status"    TEXT DEFAULT 'pending',
    "createdAt" DATETIME NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" DATETIME NOT NULL,
    "messageId" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY("messageId") REFERENCES "MessageModel"("uuid") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I can't get why is the err occurs and need help, cause I'm dummy in this ORM.

I'm using **"sequelize": "^5.1.0"** with SQLite.

MyConfig file:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const electron = require('electron');
const storagePath = electron.app.getPath('userData') + '/plt.db';

module.exports = {
  development: {
    dialect: "sqlite",
    storage: storagePath,
    username: null,
    password: null,
    operatorsAliases: Sequelize.Op,
    define: { freezeTableName: true },
    query: { raw: true }, // Always get raw result
    logging: true,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a copuple of things here. First If you are going to use `uuid` on MessageModel as primary key, you have to define it, otherwise you'll have a default `id` field.

```
const MessageModel = sequelize.define('MessageModel ', {
  uuid:{ // if this is your primary key you have to define it
    type: DataTypes.STRING,  //there is also DataTypes.UUID
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true
  }, 
  authorId: DataTypes.STRING,
  // ... other props
}, {});
```

Then on your TodoModel, you are setting the `messageId` association as integer. To change it to string, you have to define the field on the model, and on the association use it as a foreign key.

```
const TodoModel = sequelize.define('TodoModel', {
  ownerId: DataTypes.STRING,
  status: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    defaultValue: 'pending'
  },
  messageId: { //you also have to add the field on your model and set it as STRING, because on the association Sequelize by default is going to use INTEGER
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
}, {});

TodoModel.belongsTo(MessageModel , {
  as: 'Message',
  foreignKey: 'messageId', // and you only set the foreignKey - Same name as your field above
});
```